# NSDictionary to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my API response -

```
{"kitchen":"3","bath":"5","lanundry":"0","dining":"0","bedroom":"0"}
```

I have loaded this in `NSDictionary` and I can retrieve the value using key like -

```
NSDictionary *pdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];    
[pdata objectForKey:@"dining"]
```

I want add the `dictionary` object into `NSMutableArray` but it overrides the all the array values with the last one even though it adds five records.

```
itemsA=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];

 if([pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"])
    {

       [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"]];
       [img setDesc:@"Kitchen"];

       [itemsA addObject:img];
    }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"bath"])
    {
       [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"bath"]];
       [img setDesc:@"Bathroom"];
       [itemsA addObject:img];
     }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"lanundry"])
     {
        [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"lanundry"]];
        [img setDesc:@"Laundry"];
        [itemsA addObject:img];
      }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"dining"])
      {
         [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"]];
         [img setDesc:@"Kitchen"];
         [itemsA addObject:img];
       }
  if([pdata objectForKey:@"bedroom"])
      {
        [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"bedroom"]];
        [img setDesc:@"Bedroom"];
        [itemsA addObject:img];
      }
```

My table view shows 5 rows with the last value -

```
Bedroom (0)
```

But i want result like this

```
{"desc":"bathroom","count":"0"}, {"desc":"dining","count":"3"}
```

Comment: How should the resulting array look like?

Comment: you want add new object in nsmutablearray ?

Comment: i want to store as {"desc":"bathroom","count":"0"}, {"desc":"dining","count":"3"}, etc

Comment: Show your complete code. How you are parsing and storing its reponse ?

Comment: In my answer, I just pointed out the mistake what you did in your code @Tajuddin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are creating only one `img` object and re-using it. Since all objects are accessed by reference in `Objective-C`, you need to create separate `img` objects in all if conditions. Try this

```
itemsA=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 if([pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"])
    {
       imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];
       [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"]];
       [img setDesc:@"Kitchen"];

       [itemsA addObject:img];
    }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"bath"])
    {
       imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];
       [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"bath"]];
       [img setDesc:@"Bathroom"];
       [itemsA addObject:img];
     }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"lanundry"])
     {
        imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];
        [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"lanundry"]];
        [img setDesc:@"Laundry"];
        [itemsA addObject:img];
      }
 if([pdata objectForKey:@"dining"])
      {
         imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];
         [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"kitchen"]];
         [img setDesc:@"Kitchen"];
         [itemsA addObject:img];
       }
  if([pdata objectForKey:@"bedroom"])
      {
        imgCount *img=[[imgCount alloc] init];
        [img setCount:[pdata objectForKey:@"bedroom"]];
        [img setDesc:@"Bedroom"];
        [itemsA addObject:img];
      }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. You are a champ. I didn't realise I have to initialise in every block. Thank you very much.

Comment: Upvoted for this answer as you gave  understandable answer to starter

Comment: @Tajuddin I have created dictionary because in question comment you put your response like you want array of dictionary, I have edited my answer, please check once, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks @user3182143 :)

Answer (score 8):

For that you can try like this. First get all keys of dictionary then use that keys array to create array of dictionary.

```
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSDictionary *dic = @{ @"desc":key, @"count": [dict objectForKey:key] };
    [array addObject:dic];
}
NSLog(@"Array - %@",array);
```

**Edit:** If you want custom class object you can try like this.

```
 for (NSString *key in keys) {
    imgCount *imgObject=[[imgCount alloc] init];
    [imgObject setCount:[pdata objectForKey:key]];
    [imgObject setDesc:[key capitalizedString]];        
    [array addObject:imgObject];
}
```

Comment: This one is the better solution as it uses generic way to access the dictionary elements. Even I suggest this way :)

Comment: Thank you, in this case I have to modify the key in cell since I want to display proper initcap word like "Bathroom" since the key got "bathroom".

Comment: @Tajuddin Have you try using `capitalizedString` as my edited answer?

Comment: Great idea, no I haven't tried since I am happy with the other approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to get all your dictionary keys into NSMutable Array.

```
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [keys mutableCopy];
```

Comment: this is returning - `code` 2016-08-30 14:57:31.303 ACF[23914:9204243] Copy array - (
    bath,
    lanundry,
    dining,
    bedroom,
    kitchen
)